# What's wrong with this proof that $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be well-ordered?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders, infinitary-combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with the following proof that $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be well ordered (and thus, ZFC is inconsistent). It's based off a special case of the [Erdős–Dushnik–Miller theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Dushnik%E2%80%93Miller_theorem)/Ramsey's Theorem for Infinite Graphs as well as the fact the natural linear total order $(<)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be a well ordering, even for any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Ok, here it is:

Assume there exists a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$, $(\mathbb{R},\prec)$ and partion the pairs of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ into two sets, $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that:

- $\{a,b\}\in P_1$ iff $a\prec b \iff a<b$, and
- $\{a,b\}\in P_2$ iff $a\prec b \iff b<a$.

$P_1$ and $P_2$ are well defined since $\prec$ and $<$ are both total orders. Pick any $a_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Then since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, at least one of the sets $S_i:=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\; \text{and } \{a_0,x\}\in P_i\}$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ is uncountable. Let $S_{i_0}$ be such a set. Pick another number $a_1$ from $S_{i_0}\setminus\{a_0\}$. Then as in the case of $a_0$, there exist uncountable many real numbers $x$ in $S_{i_0}\setminus\{a_0,\;a_1\}$ such that for all of these $x$, all of the pairs $\{a_1,x\}$ belong to one of the $P_i$. Let $S_{i_1}$ be such a set. Then assuming $\mathsf{AC}$ (which we get by working under the assumption that every set can be well ordered), there are uncountably many $a_j$ and associated nested subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $S_{i_j}$ such that all of the $S_{i_j}$ are uncountable and all the pairs $\{a_j,x\}$ for every $x\in S_{i_j}$ are in $P_{i_j}$ for some $i_j\in\{0,1\}$.

Now there are uncountably many indices $j$ so there must be an uncountable number of the $i_j$ equal to $1$ or $2$. This means that there must be an uncountable number of $a_j$ such for one of the $P_i$, all of the pairs of those $a_j$ are in $P_i$. Let $A$ be the set of these $a_j$. Suppose first that all the pairs of reals in $A$ are in $P_1$. Since we are operating under the assumption that $\prec$ well orders $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $A$, and the fact that $\prec$ agrees with the regular linear order on all pairs of reals in $P_1$ we reach a contradiction: $A$ is uncountable by construction and $<$ does not well order any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now assume all of the pairs of reals in $A$ are in $P_2$. Define $B:=\{-a\mid\; a\in A,\, a\neq0\}$ where negation here is the usual negation with respect to the linear order. Then by the definition of $P_2$ and the basic property of inequality, for all $b_1,\; b_2\in B$, $b_1<b_2\iff b_1\prec b_2$ and thus in this case the linear order on $B$ also agrees with the supposed well order $\prec$ on $B$ and we get the same contradiction because $B$ is uncountable just as $A$ is.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong because the proof closely follows the constructive proof for Ramsey's Theorem for infinite graphs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence starting with "Then assuming AC...".  Can you elaborate?  How exactly are you obtaining the $a_j$ and $S_{i_j}$?  How can you arrange for the $S_{i_j}$ to be nested?

Comment: @EricWofsey By AC, I mean the axiom of choice, that is making uncountably many choices picking new $a_j$ and finding an uncountable subset of $S_{i_0}$ (they keep getting smaller each time, that is nested) and the $S_{i_j}$ is either going to be sets whose points paired with the $a_j$ are in $P_1$ or $P_2$. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, but are you working in ZF or in ZFC? You keep asking these questions about ZF, but really you're asking plain questions in ZFC.

Comment: I agree that you can define $a_2$ and $S_{i_2}$, then $a_3$ and $S_{i_3}$, and so on.  But how do you get *uncountably many* such $a_j$?

Comment: What makes you think that a nested sequence of uncountable sets has uncountable intersection (let alone non-empty intersection)?

Comment: The framing is off here... this is a (purported) proof of the inconsistency of ZFC... not of “if ZF is consistent, then...”. (And since you claim to use AC right where it goes off the rails it’s not clear which fragment is being proven inconsistent... perhaps not just ZF + the reals can be well-ordered... not that it matters much since, per Godel, if ZFC is inconsistent then ZF is inconsistent as well.)

Comment: @jonathan It's not that the uncountable sets are guaranteed to have an nonempty intersection, rather the set $A$ is formed from the uncountably many chosen $a_j$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, I wasn't sure how to phrase the question because it does imply that ZF is inconsistent by way of the relative consistency proof of ZF + AC by Godel, however since that was a proof of relative consistency and this would be a direct one I opted for the title I chose

Comment: @Ari I suppose if you have shown ZFC is inconsistent, then you have shown ZF is inconsistent, and then you have shown “if ZF is consistent, then the moon is made of Green cheese” so it’s not, strictly speaking, inaccurate to phrase it that way :).

Comment: @Ari Then how do you find $a_j$ when the intersection of all the previous $S_i$ is empty?

Comment: @jonathan Because that's the (paradoxical) way the axiom of choice works for picking an uncountable number of points. Consider this: given the interval $(0,1)$ pick a real $a_0\in (0,1)$ then pick another real $a_1\in (0,a_0)$, then $a_2\in (0,a_1)$. The intervals keep getting smaller and smaller so the infinite intersection is empty, but because we're dealing with the continuum we can keep picking uncountably many $a_i$ so the set of them is uncountable.

Comment: @Ari No. This is not how the axiom of choice works. It doesn't let you magically choose something from the empty set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry to be unclear. My proof shows that if we assume ZFC is consistent then we get a contradiction, thus implying through the relative consistency proof of the consistency of ZF + AC, then ZF would be inconsistent.

Comment: Sure. But you're framing this in a confusing way. We know that ZF and ZFC are equiconsistent. If you're relying on AC, just talk about ZFC.

Comment: @jonathan But as in my example, non of the intervals $(0,a_i)$ are empty. It's just the property of taking an infinite intersection of them all together that we are left with the empty set.

Comment: Also, to elaborate on what @Jonathan is alluding to, note that $(n,n+1)$ are uncountable, but their intersection is empty. And $(n,\infty)$ form a decreasing sequence of uncountable sets with empty intersection.

Comment: Your argument depends on choosing each $a_j$ to be in the intersection of all the previous $S_{i_k}$'s (where "previous" means $k<j$). That works fine for all finite $j$, but as soon as you've completed an infinite sequence of choices, you need to choose $a_\omega$ from the intersection of all infinitely many of the previous $S_{i_k}$'s, and unfortunately, as @Jonathan pointed out, that intersection may well be empty. So, instead of getting uncountably many $a_j$'s, you might get just a countable sequence of them. And that proves a weak form of Ramsey's theorem, not a contradiction.

Comment: @AndreasBlass While it is certainly true that even a countable intersection of uncountable sets may be empty, that does not preclude us from picking uncountably many $a_j$ in this situation due the nature of the construction. This can be proven through transfinite induction...

Comment: @AndreasBlass ... Let $T_k:=\bigcap_{j<k}S_{i_j}$. Claim: $T_k$ is uncountable for all $k$. This is certainly true for $T_1$ because it is the first step of the construction. Now assume $T_k$ is uncountable. The sets $S_{1_k}$ and $S_{2_k}$ partition $T_k$ so at least one of them must be uncountable. Then when we take the induction step and include an uncountable $S_{i_k}$ in the intersection, we still have an uncountable set. Thus, we will never exhaust the possiblity of choosing uncountably many $a_j$.

Comment: @Ari You seem to confuse transfinite induction with ordinary induction. Specifically, the "proof" in your last comment omits the step for limit ordinal stages.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ok, but then according to your reasoning how can the Axiom of Choice even be a possibility? That is, how can we be sure that we can take uncountably many elements from an uncountable set without exhausting the set?

Comment: @Ari To take uncountably many elements from  a given uncountable set $S$, use AC to well-order $S$ and then take every second set in the well-ordering.